# How can i make my page title to be on top of everything in wordpress ? I am using elementor hello theme and elementor pro

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

```css
h1.entry-title {
z-index: 9999;
color: #F23400;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 44px;
font-weight: 800;
font-style: italic;
text-align: center;
line-height: 15;
-webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
-moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox < 16 */
-ms-animation: fadein 3s; /* Internet Explorer */
-o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
animation: fadein 3s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */ @-moz-keyframes fadein { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; } } /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to { opacity: 1; }

z-index: 9999;
}
```

This is what i have tried with no luck. I am sorry if this was answered before. I have set the background image to -1 that is on this page, and the title to 9999 with z-index. I am using elementor pro to do such editing on that image.

Comment: I don't see your css title selector! Is that a typo?

Comment: yes sorry, i corrected it now , i think